# Type inference based on method parameters?

Tags: c#

I have a method with the following signature:

```
async Task<object> Foo(object a, object b);
```

If I use it thus:

```
dynamic c = new ExpandoObject();

var x = await Foo(new object(), c);
```

The compiler uses `dynamic` as the inferred type for x.

```
var x = await Foo(new object(), (object)c);
```

The compiler uses `object` as the inferred type for x.

I would have expected both to use `object` as the inferred type since the return type of the method return type is `Task<object>`.  Can anyone offer any insight into the reasoning behind inferring the type from method parameters?

Comment: Dynamic is - for lack of a better term - infective. If you hand a dynamic value to a function and it is used in math to get the result - the result will become dynamic. This will override the normal function return type.

Comment: This is specific to `dynamic`. If you're telling the compiler to deal with the type at runtime, it can't make inferences about the return type of the method. Consider cases where you have multiple implementations of `Foo`, and a different one may be called depending on the runtime type of your dynamic variable.